Which denominations of Christianity are against the easement of suffering via medical science, and what is the justification that they use?
I am curious to learn which (if any!) sects/denominations/cults of christianity are totally against reducing human suffering related to illnesses via medical science.
I believe this is significantly different then the other more general question on this site.
A negative example: I am aware that the Jehovah's Witness are against blood transfusions, this would be an example of what I am NOT looking for due to the fact that the opposition is limited in scope to just blood transfusions.
To my knowledge the following denominations have issues with "SOME" aspects of medical treatments. But none of them are "fully opposed" which is what I am asking for.

The Amish (do not have doctrinal opposition to medical care, but tend to favor natural remedies)
The Assembly of God
Bapticostal Church (West virginia)
"Christian Science" (Possibly opposed to all, but not clear in my search)
Church of God (some congregations are fixated on faith healers)
Church of the first born (Religious based neglect of children, but not of medical treatments in general or as a whole)
End Time Ministries (Child related, medical care related to children, but not adults)
Faith Assembly (Child related only)
One Mind Ministries (Child related exorcism)
True Followers of Christ Church (Oklahoma, medical neglect of children only, not adults, not universally)
Unleavened Bread Ministries (Wisconsin, child dies of untreated diabetes... seems limited to children again)

One that is close that I found is "The Church of Christ, Scientist"
The Church of Christ, Scientist, for example, is a denomination that promotes healing of physical and mental illnesses and disorders through prayer. They do compromise somewhat in the case of broken bones. There are many cases of apparently preventable deaths due to reliance on faith healing by Christian Scientist. Due to the broken bones aspect it doesn't seem to fit my criteria...


No discussion on this subject would be complete without mentioning the parable of the drowning man.

@Matthew I have had that story in the back of my mind, though it is not directly related. From our perspective it is clear that God sends us assistance in the material world as well as the spiritual one. This is why I am curious about these denominations and how the justify something that seems contrary to things I see in the Bible.

It depends what the reason is for rejecting medicine. It seems that reason is often a belief that one should "have faith". But God works through worldly means; as well "have faith" in being fed by manna from heaven rather than going to the store to buy food. However, you're right that there may be other reasons, which would be interesting to know!

Over 40 years ago, I knocked at the door of a house (cold-calling), and the young woman who answered the knock invited me in as we were mutually interested in the matter of Christian faith. She said she and her husband were members of the Christian Science religion.
She explained what their views were regarding avoiding all medicine. This ranged from never taking any pain-killers for toothache (for example) to dying for lack of a medical intervention. This was not restricted to children, but included adults as well. She spoke about how she had suffered great pain for one ailment, due to refusing medicine, but stuck to her refusal, and her faith. She said she would be prepared to die for that.
Her claim was that anyone with faith in God would pray for his healing, and God would give it to those having total faith. The rationale was that to pray, then to accept human methods, would be a contradiction in terms. One had to have total faith in God healing in order for that prayer to "work". To then use human methods would be gross hypocrisy which would cancel out the prayer.
Obviously, I'm not quoting verbatim, a conversation of +40 years ago! This is a personal encounter, however, and I have remembered it because I was quite shocked, never having come directly into contact with a person with such a view. However, I have a booklet here which explains the ground for this view, due to the founder's experiences:

It was while she was married to Dr. Patterson that she visited the
then famous P.P. Quimby at Portland, Maine, a drugless healer who
practiced a type of mind-cure which included dipping his hands in
water and then rubbing the patient's head.
"He told her that her ailments - and all diseases - were traceable to
causes in the invisible world of mind; that mental factors produced
powerful changes in the fluids and processes of the body;  and that he
was able, by some sort of electrical transference, to take the
patient's ills upon himself and destroy them. While at this period he
did not consider himself a mesmerist hypnotist), the methods he used
would today be considered a form of mental suggestion" Quoted from
The Christian Science Way of Life, pp. 142, 143, in the booklet, Christian Science in the Light of the Scriptures, p. 6, Harold J. Berry, 1970 reprint

My contact with that lady must have been around the early 1980s and the booklet I have quoted from was dated 1964. The author gives more information, explaining how that Christian Science book, The Christian Science Way of Life strongly denies their beliefs to have been based on Quimby (pp.151-156) but saying there are only "superficial resemblances" is odd. He admits that both groups (Quimbyism and Christian Science) agree that there is no intelligence in matter. Both agree that sickness is 'error' or 'belief'. Then, the founder later had another experience of intense pain, possibly due to a spinal injury, which led to studying Matthew 9, the healing of the palsied man by Christ. She said:

"Like a shaft of light when the sun flashes briefly through black and
heavy clouds, there came in this hour of suffering a spiritual
illumination. It was a clear view of Life totally apart from earthly
scenes, wholly separate from matter and material living, a new world
of spiritual consciousness." The Christian Science Way of Life, p. 144

Towards he end of 1866, Mrs. Patterson had completed studying biblical accounts of healing, and then she had:

"...reached the scientific certainty that all causation rests with
Mind, and that every effect is a mental phenomenon." (Ibid, p. 148)

The booklet then says these were her instructions to those in Christian Science who dealt, as practitioners, with sick people:

"If they ask about their diseases, tell them only what is best for
them to know. Assure them that they think too much about their
ailments, and have already heard too much on that subject. Turn their
thoughts away from their bodies to higher objects. Teach them that
their being is sustained by Spirit, not by matter, and that they find
health, peace, and harmony in God, divine Love. Give sick people
credit for sometimes knowing more than their doctors. Always support
their trust in the power of Mind to sustain the body." Science and
Health, p. 416, line 27 to p. 417, line 5.

The Christian Science member I spoke with +40 years ago would most likely have that information from the founder, as written in those two Christian Science publications cited. More modern literature and explanations from the religion could be different now, of course, but the material I quote from was closer to the time when Christian Science was founded, being 'only' about 100 years on, whereas now it is 160 years on. I hope some Christian Science followers answer.

From my understanding your answer is very correct, though I believe they had an exception lately for broken bones. Regardless thank you for the answer it is interesting. I do believe in a lot of "mind over matter" and "power of prayer" but not to the point of refusing science. Remember painkillers are more effective if they taste bad. ...

@IanGoldby  On this Stack Christianity (& Hermenutics) site, describing any group that identifies itself as 'Christian' as being 'a heretical site' is frowned upon. On this site (which is not a Christian site) the idea seems to be that "If you think you are a Christian, then you must be a Christian." No comment. I just add that when I knocked on that door, I was convinced my group was the only Christian one and that all others were heretics! I've since left it, but perhaps it takes one to know one.

@Anne How frustrating to learn that comment manipulation goes on here. I will start to maintain a copy as well.

One possible denomination that I've found is "Faith Tabernacle" (USA, PA)

A coroner said, "I don't think there is any criminal neglect about this. . . . They feel if you're called upon to die, you die." (CHILD Newsletter #3 1997 p9)

The above quote is regarding the Winterborne family who lost 6 children one after another over the course of 9 years to bronchial pneumonia between 1971 and 1980.

Though Roger Winterbome expressed grief for
the deaths of his babies, he also told the press after
Jocelyn's [the fifth child] death, "When you believe in something,
you have to believe in it all the way. If you only
believe in it part way, it's not a true belief."
"God knows more than we do."

When I was digging further... I could find this, but not sources from Faith Tabernacle itself (All searches I made seem to talk about a mega church in Nigeria...)

Faith Tabernacle rejects any and all forms of medical intervention, from vaccinations to visits to the doctor's office.
Church members are forbidden to wear glasses or hearing aids. They may not use canes or walkers. Children are not vaccinated. Aspirin, Advil, cough syrup, thermometers -- anything not directly linked to prayer -- is forbidden. Herbal teas that impart medicinal properties, such as chamomile tea, are banned.
Women are forbidden to use tampons (the church believes they compromise a woman's virtue). Midwives are not allowed during childbirth, although the presence of an experienced woman is not discouraged. Alcohol and cigarettes are rigorously banned, as is premarital sex.

Obviously the source above is secular news, so gotta get that jab in about premarital sex. The article is mostly about laws within the USA, PA state where religious exemptions are very strong for medical treatments.

I have not been able to find the proper justification though. Every article or source I've found just "claims" (accurately) that this denomination refuses medical treatment, but not "why"
